# undefined method `[]' for "jpg":Sass::Script::Value::String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After upgrading to Rails 4 I get some strange errors when trying to get my application up and running.

```
= favicon_link_tag "favicon.png"
```

Produces an error:

```
undefined method `[]' for "jpg":Sass::Script::Value::String
```

Below is the full stacktrace that produces the error:

```
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:174:in `compute_asset_extname'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:130:in `asset_path'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:124:in `asset_path'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:143:in `_perform'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:58:in `perform'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:173:in `perform_arg'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:124:in `block in _perform'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:124:in `each'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:124:in `each_with_index'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:124:in `each'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:124:in `map'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:124:in `_perform'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:58:in `perform'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/script/tree/list_literal.rb:63:in `block in _perform'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/script/tree/list_literal.rb:63:in `map'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/script/tree/list_literal.rb:63:in `_perform'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:58:in `perform'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:397:in `visit_prop'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:433:in `block (2 levels) in visit_rule'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:433:in `map'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:433:in `block in visit_rule'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in `with_environment'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:431:in `visit_rule'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:433:in `block (2 levels) in visit_rule'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:433:in `map'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:433:in `block in visit_rule'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in `with_environment'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:431:in `visit_rule'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:169:in `block in visit_children'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in `with_environment'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:168:in `visit_children'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:188:in `visit_root'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:159:in `visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/engine.rb:281:in `render'
sass-rails (5.0.6) lib/sass/rails/template.rb:47:in `evaluate'
tilt (2.0.5) lib/tilt/template.rb:102:in `render'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/legacy_tilt_processor.rb:25:in `call'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:196:in `dfs'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:50:in `each'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:50:in `map'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:50:in `precompiled_assets'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:35:in `asset_precompiled?'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:251:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:359:in `precompiled?'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:363:in `raise_unless_precompiled_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:337:in `digest_path'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:325:in `asset_path'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:102:in `block in resolve_asset_path'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:242:in `block in resolve_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:241:in `each'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:241:in `detect'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:241:in `resolve_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:101:in `resolve_asset_path'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:79:in `compute_asset_path'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:135:in `asset_path'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:292:in `image_path'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:176:in `favicon_link_tag'
app/views/layouts/application.haml:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_haml___2916998330693644908_70147654436540'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:66:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:46:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:27:in `render'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/Users/hendricius/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.2.7) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.7) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
rack-cors (0.4.0) lib/rack/cors.rb:80:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
request_store (1.3.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.7) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Has anyone seen something similar?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/279

Comment: That one doesn't fix the issue unfortunately, I tried it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately ended up upgrading my Rails 3 project to Rails 4. Then all the errors were gone.